# Go JSON:API (google/jsonapi) Pagination Example

Tags: go, json-api

Can someone show an example of how to output pagination links in the response using [google/jsonapi](https://github.com/google/jsonapi)?  I've tried a couple approaches and none seems to work.  I can directly output the object or an array of objects using `MarshalPayload()` and add links to the nodes by using the `Linkable` interface.  I haven't yet seen an interface for the top level object so this is my current implementation.

```golang
        resp := map[string]interface{}{
            "data": users,
            "links": jsonapi.Links{
                "next": "next/2",
            },
        }

        c.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderContentType, jsonapi.MediaType)
        err = jsonapi.MarshalPayload(c.Response(), resp)
        if err != nil {
            return echo.ErrInternalServerError
        }
```

Which is complaining that:
`models should be a struct pointer or slice of struct pointers`.  The output I'm looking for is something similar to the one on the [JSON:API Homepage](https://jsonapi.org/).  For example:

```json
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles",
    "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=10"
  },
  "data": ...<snipped>
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your `resp` Map. That needs to be a struct. So you would need something like this:

```
type Resp struct {
    Data []String `jsonapi:...`
    Links []Link `jsonapi:...`
}

resp := new (Resp)

//here add your values to resp
//like: resp.Data = users 

c.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderContentType, jsonapi.MediaType)
err = jsonapi.MarshalPayload(c.Response(), resp)
if err != nil {
    return echo.ErrInternalServerError
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's my sample code:

```
type User struct {
    ID   int    `jsonapi:"primary,user"`
    Name string `jsonapi:"attr,name"`
}

type Articles struct {
    Users []*User `jsonapi:"relation,users"`
}
```

Handler function: (I didnt add any error handling, but you should)

```
func (env *Env) TryJSONAPI(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    resp := []*User{
        {ID: 3, Name: "username1"},
    }
    p, _ := jsonapi.Marshal(resp)
    payload, _ := p.(*jsonapi.ManyPayload)
    payload.Links = &jsonapi.Links{
        "self": fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/articles"),
        "next": fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/articles?page[offset]=%d", 2),
        "last": fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/articles?page[offset]=%d", 10),
    }
    if err := json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(payload); err != nil {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      type: "user",
      id: "3",
      attributes: {
        name: "username1"
      }
    }
  ],
  links: {
    last: "https://example.com/articles?page[offset]=10",
    next: "https://example.com/articles?page[offset]=2",
    self: "https://example.com/articles"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not getting me there.  Can you do a complete implementation?  `MarshalPayload` expects a `model interface{}`.  I tried directly creating a `jsonapi.ManyPayload` with no luck.  It feels like the `Linkable` interface is the right way to do it but at the wrong level (meaning it should be above the top level `Node` object) and their should be an interface somewhere. Ty

Comment: @JSP see if the above update is what you need

Comment: It does work but can you walk me through this?  I seems pretty bizarre that there isn't a way to add pagination links with `google/jsonapi`, it looks like it's encoded twice, and I have to use `encoding/json` to output the result.  The `Linkable` interface makes so much more sense to me (or something like it).  Anyway, I can't argue with the results.

Comment: @JSP this is because you want top level `links`. The golang api works on structs so the `Linkable` interface also applies on structs. But in doing that the top level attr would be `data`. I think they have had a feature request for a while to add what you are looking for, hasnt seen the light of day yet